# Need a little reg-exp help

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm horrible at reg-exp's, so I need a little help getting it right.

I got a PHP-variable containing HTML-code created from a PDF. The pages are separate with a comment in the following style:

```
<!-- Page 1 -->
```

What I need is to split the content on each of these comment so I can separate the pages from eachother. I tried using just `explode('<!-- Page', $content)`, but that leaves the rest of the tag on the start of the next page so obviously it's not a good enough solution.

So what I need help with is finding a reg-exp that will split on `<!-- Page X -->` where the X can be any number. Anyone able to help me out?

Comment: If you use a Regex tool such as [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) then you'll be able to write these yourself pretty easily.

Comment: @Town Seems like a nice tool, I'll give it a try:) Thanks for the advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work just fine;

```
<?php

$foo = '

Hello.

<!-- Page 2 -->

Bar

<!-- Page 3 -->

Foo
';

$pages = array_map( 'trim', preg_split( '~<!-- Page (\d+) -->~m', $foo ) );

var_dump( $pages );
```

Output:

```
berry@berry-pc:~$ php foo.php 
    array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Hello."
  [1]=>
  string(3) "Bar"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "Foo"
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't know PHP, but I'm fairly sure you'll want a + after \d to indicate one or more digits (for pages 10+)

Comment: The pattern you use seems to match only _Page 0_ to _Page 9_ but I think it should also match _Page 42_ or _Page 102_... the pattern must be `\d+` instead of `\d`

Answer (score 3):

simple regex:

```
<!-- Page [0-9]+ -->
```